# CSS Specificity Issue

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How to calculate specificity in CSS? Though that is not my final question , I declared a class for a Div but the styles are not getting affected though I declared the class at last.

I have my code like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="App.css" />
    ...........
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="apply.css" />
   <div class="class1 class2 class3 classDesired"> ..........</div>
```

and assume that apply.css contains classDesired class  , Still the div style is getting affected by App.css  but not apply.css eventhough I declared it last.  Later I found out that it may be due to specificity issue.  How to calculate specificity in CSS?

Comment: please show your css code too

Comment: Name your CSS classes with `div.parent-div > .classDesired`. Or put `!important` on the CSS you want to take president over the other classes.

Comment: @MikeBarwick There are few reason to use `important`. this is not one of them.

Comment: HTML rendering is sequential, which means that it will render the CSS from the first linked CSS file, followed by the next, followed by the next ... etc. It sounds like your problem isn't really about that, but rather the rules you have within those stylesheets not doing what you want. So post your problem code in a fiddle, and we can take a look.

Comment: I agree 100% - but it is a route one can take. Not one I would...

Comment: Like Ankur said, please post code from both of your CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Specificity is **not** about `a` after `b` or `b` after `a`

It's about :

`a`(which has **id** `A`) vs `a`(which has **class** `A`)...... ( just a sample)

take a look at how to calc specifity :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use hierarchy for the class that you are using.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="classDesired">
        some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `CSS` goes here

```
.parent div.classDesired
{
   .. some css
}
```